# Ошибка в команде yarn install

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, yarn

Установил Docker Toolbox for Windows 8.1
В контейнеры через docker-compose установил nginx, php-fpm, php-cli, nodejs
Установил symfony 4.3

В symfony 4.3 установил encore: `"symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.7",`

При попытке запустить команду `docker-compose run --rm manager-node yarn install`
в терминале phpstorm получаю ошибку:

```
D:\work\5_project-manager>docker-compose run --rm manager-node yarn install
yarn install v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
New state of 'nil' is invalid..0
```

Содержимое файла package.json не менял (оно сгенерилось после установки encore):

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.28.0",
        "core-js": "^3.0.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.2",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    }
}
```

Но что интересно, если удалить содержимое devDependencies и оставить его пустым:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    }
}
```

и запустить команду `docker-compose run --rm manager-node yarn install` то она отрабатывает БЕЗ ОШИБОК и создаёт пустой yarn.lock файл и пустую папку node_modules

```
D:\work\5_project-manager>docker-compose run --rm manager-node yarn install
yarn install v1.19.1
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 0.14s.
```